# Protractor is not able to find a function from JS file

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

I created a function which return the new Browser object from the JS function `browser.forkNewDriverInstance()` and i created a global variable in my config file and i'm calling a function from that file by using this global variable. but here when i'm calling that function it is throwing error like `utility.openNewBrowser is not a function` error.

### Config File:

```
onPrepare: function () {
     
     global.utility=require("../src/test/resources/com.learnFramework.utility/timeOutConfig.js");
  }
```

### Cucumber Opts functions

```
cucumberOpts: {

//i'm using the same file for setting up the timeout.. is this creating the issue??

    require:['../src/test/resources/com.learnFramework.utility/timeOutConfig.js'],
    tags: false,
    profile: false,
    format:'json:../Reports/jsonResult/results.json',
    'no-source': true
}
```

### Function

```
var configure = function () {
      this.setDefaultTimeout(100 * 1000);
        
        this.openNewBrowser=function(){
            return browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
        }
    };

    module.exports = configure;
```

### Error Log

```
TypeError: utility.openNewBrowser is not a function
```

When i called the forkNewBrowserInstance method directly i'm getting the below error.

```
both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined. This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping. See http://git.io/v4gXM for details
```

can some help  me to resolve this issue.. i got this error because the first browser ignoring synchronization but second browser how can i ignore the synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

What you did above is the correct way of defining a global variable. But I think the global variable name should be `configure` instead of `utility` that is why it is throwing the TypeError.

And wherever you want to call it, use that variable name as is. This is actually how protractor, browser and other built-in global variables [were made available globally](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f2a11a7369319edac0f1221a1c6ab0f9a2cc73eb/lib/runner.js#L152). The following [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208642/1976848) was helpful and also the [protractor doc](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/37bef24331c1012bfc2cc7d3fa259a00e69bd192/lib/config.ts#L532) where it's explaining the property: params?: any;

Hope this helps, please let me know.

Comment: it's not working.. i changed the global variable name but still the same issue

Comment: @SatishRongala Import timeoutConfig.js file only once and call the methods `openBrowser` and 'setDefaultTimeout` Under OnPrepare and CucumberOpts. Also in the last lines of the post have you checked whether the page is Angular or NonAngular. Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37747440/1976848 .

Comment: i got a solution for this but i got stuck with another issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888844 .. please check it if you able to solve this one..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but with jasmine. 
so i had done the following workaround and issue was resolved.

```
class abc{
      constructor() {
         var configure = function () {
         this.setDefaultTimeout(100 * 1000);    
         this.openNewBrowser=function(){
         return browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);
        }
    };

}
}
module.exports = new abc();
```